# Настройка LESS переменных в файле variables.less YII2

Tags: bootstrap, yii2, less, yii-bootstrap

Темы Bootstrap3 почти на 99% настраиваются под себя LESS переменными в файле variables.less без создания дополнительных "костылей".

Можно просто переназначить под себя переменные типа:

> @brand-primary:        Цвет акцента
>
> @brand-success:        зеленый
>
> @brand-info:              синий;
>
> @brand-warning:       желтый;
>
> @brand-danger:         красный
>
> @body-bg:                  цвет body;
>
> @text-color                 цвет текста
>
> @font-size-base         размер шрифта на странице
>
> @border-radius-base: базовый радиус скругления углов элементов

и многое другое.

Эти переменные глобальные для Bootstrap и действуют на все его элементы, по этому проще настроить их именно здесь.
При изменении этих переменных в **vendor/bower/bootstrap/less/variables.less** никакого эффекта почему то не наблюдается.

Как это сделать в YII2 так и не нашел информации... Везде предлагается создать файл, перезаписывающий стили Bootstrap.
Считаю это принципиально не правильным.

Вопрос:
**как настроить вышеописанные переменные LESS Bootstrap в YII2 под себя?**

Если это не возможно, то как отключить стили (только стили!) встроенного Bootstrap чтобы подключить свою управляемую сборку стилей Bootstrap3?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Прошу простить если ошибаюсь,но мне кажется вы ранее не сталкивались с .less
Дело в том что там итоговый файл стилей компилируются,"генерируется" специальным препроцессором - он может к примеру называться less.js или по другому,в зависимости от того как вы "компилируете" этот итоговый файл стилей.
Второй момент - в Yii2 есть такая вещь как ассеты,там вы можете указать в составе вашего ассета файл с описанием именно ваших стилей в less.
Там все происходит почти автоматически на самом деле :)
*When you register such an asset bundle with a view, the asset manager will automatically run the pre-processor tools to convert assets in recognized extended syntax into CSS/JavaScript.* 
Вот посмотрите раздел Asset Conversion
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html
там подробно описано как настроить ассеты так что бы при изменении в вашем site.less происходило изменение на вашем сайте.

Comment: я вот про это говорю: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045361/compiling-custom-bootstrap-css-in-yii2-from-less но тут так всё мудрено.... не ужели нет способа проще?

Comment: Можно. На самом деле и в примере приведенном вами и в любом другом происходит компиляция итогового файла стилей в нужном месте.Вот пример если делать вручную после правки файла .less (по сути миксина) с вашими доработками бутстрепа

php yii asset assets.php config/assets-dev.php
lessc site.less site.css

то есть я должен вводить эти две команды в консоли и файл стилей одного из моих проектов будет "пересобираться".
Из этого просто выходит разнообразная коллекция всяких костылей - где и как выполнить эту команду.